# Laravel 5.4 Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I need to create a custom login auth for email verification, I will post some snippets to give you an idea of the problem:

But, i receive the following **Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist**

Stack overflow is saying i need more text as it is mostly code, i hope this excpert here will be enough to bump it up.

The login.blade - default that comes with auth, just tweaked slightyl

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('loginc') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>

                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

loginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginControllerCustom extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
public function login(Request $request)
{

        return 'boo';
        $this->validateLogin($request);
 {

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string|max:150',
        'password' => 'required|string|max:150',
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: The full error message would be useful. As it stands we can only *guess* where the error occurs, and so whether the code you posted is actually relevant.

Answer (score 9):

You are not using the required namespace, try to use the following in your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

You are getting the error due to the fact that your script tries to load the Request class from the current namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`

Answer (score 3):

try adding this line in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: ... and remove this wrong import (`use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request`)

Answer (score 0):

In your namespace use the below code or include in your namespace for the error request to be found:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```